# TFS Admin Console

Tags: sql, tfs, backup, restore

I wonder that about this problem: `tfs_configuration` & my `tfs_testcollection` in `TFS Admin Console` and `SQL MS`.

What is recommended solution for backups and restore `tfs_configuration` in `TFS Admin Console` ? I ask because sometimes it happens that collection and configuration are out of sync ? Could you recomend best solution for preventing these problems? Any msdn site or books or blog with solutions ?

Thank you in advance.
Lucas.

Answer (score 0):

It's because this out of sync, is recommended you do the backup by Admin console, using the tools Backup! This feature will syncronize all database of TFS, including Reports, Sharepoint, etc..

Answer (score 0):

The only supported and documented method of creating a backup in TFS is to use marked transaction logs. In versions before 2010 this was a manual process documented on MSDN. In 2010 the TFS team added a tool to the Power Tool to make it easyer. That tool was a big set up but was still a little flakie around the edges. In 2012 update 2 this was finally consistent enough to make it into the tool and be available in the Admin Console.

I have a blog post and video on how to configure the manual and power tool option: http://nakedalm.com/creating-a-backup-in-team-foundation-server-2010-using-the-power-tools/

You can find full documentation on MSDN.